# external javascript doesn't read a file into directory

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function myFunction (){

    var xr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "saveNewText.php";
    var text = document.getElementById('editable').innerHTML;
    var vars = "newText="+text;

    xr.open("POST", url, true);
    xr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xr.send(vars);

}
```

It works fine when the php file is in the root but when i put it into directory like php and change to var url = "php/saveNewText.php"; it dosen't work.

Any idea????

Comment: Does the pho folder exist already?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction (){

var xr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "./php/saveNewText.php";
var text = document.getElementById('editable').innerHTML;
var vars = "newText="+text;

xr.open("POST", url, true);
xr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xr.send(vars);
}
```

Not sure if this will work, try it though.

Reply and tell me if it's working OK.

Comment: What did you change and why?

Comment: ./ and ../ refer to localhost and it dosen't work, i try every variant of that and the problem is the same... the php file in the root is ready, but when i put into a directory the script dosent work...

Comment: That's very interesting, make sure you have the permissions set to 777 on your webserver.